# Javascript: scrollTo() vs scroll(), which is the accepted/standard method

Tags: javascript, scroll, web-standards

I know that both `scroll()` and `scrollTo()` do the same thing and that browsers support both to ensure backwards compatibility, but which one is deprecated? Which one should I be using? And is there a way to prevent a browser from storing the scroll position on a page so that I don't have to use a `"beforeunload"` event listener to reset my scroll position to (0,0) right before the user leaves the page? I would always like my page to be rendered every time with the scroll position at (0,0), because it's more of an interactive game than a website, and requires this functionality.

W3Schools seems to only reference `scrollTo()`, so this may be the standard. Still, a workaround for the `"beforeunload"` event listener would be nice so that my page always starts at scroll position (0,0) without the extra listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The W3 actually lists both methods in their spec of the Window interface:
http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#extensions-to-the-window-interface

You can safely use either one.

Comment: It is indeed, it's just how everything evolved before there were any standards. Unfortunately I don't think there is a way to get around resetting the scroll position as I believe browsers handle that natively. You might also try forcing the scroll to (0,0) whenever the page loads.

Comment: Is there a way to force scroll? Right now using "beforeunload" works, but explicitly calling `window.scrollTo(0,0)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure - haven't tried it myself that's why I offered it as a suggestion. Perhaps you can try to execute it as soon as content starts loading by placing a `<script>` tag immediately after your opening `<body>` element or right before you close it `</body>`.

Comment: `scrollTo` works on desktop just fine. I think my problem may have been related to zoom more so than scroll position. Also, Firefox for Android is my problematic browser. It fires a screen `resize` event after `window.onload` before it gets client dimensions. I've since come to accept that hardly anything that looks standard in web design stands as a cross browser solution. On the other hand, `scrollTo` works pretty well in general. I'm going to stick with it above `scroll` and continue testing in all of my mobile browsers until I get it right.